# Powershell Script to get external IP address from a list of computers

Tags: loops, powershell, ip

I have been trying to get this script to get the external IP address of multiple machines on my network. So far, the script seems to iterate through the loop but run the command on my local machine rather than the remote one on the loop.

```
$computers = get-content "c:\scripts\scriptdev\Addresses.txt"
$outfile ="c:\scripts\scriptdev\test2.csv"

$results = @()
foreach ($computer in $computers)
{
Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/json | Select -exp ip $computer
Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name $computer
}
```

Comment: So unclear. You never "asked" any cmdlets to execute remotely... `$results` and `$outfile` are never used. You entered `$computer` as a column name for `Select-Object` which would make it generate objects that have their own properties (not just values)..

Comment: *the external IP address of multiple machines on my network* - unless you know for sure that is configured simply in your network, there's no definite single external IP address for a computer. There are many reasons there might be more than one external IP address - multiple WAN connections, different policies depending on who is logged in or time of day, different routing for different protocols, multiple IPs for different incoming services (HTTPS, SSH)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a cmdlet or parameter to specify remote execution. `$computer` by itself is just a variable with a string-value.

Some cmdlets support a `-ComputerName $computer` paramter, while others like `Invoke-RestMethod` require that you run them using `Invoke-Command` or something similar.

Ex.

```
$computers = get-content "c:\scripts\scriptdev\Addresses.txt"
$results = @()

foreach ($computer in $computers)
{
    $results += Invoke-Command -HideComputerName -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
        New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
            Name = Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name
            ExternalIP = Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/json | Select -ExpandProperty ip
        }
    }
}

$results
```

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot. Do you know how I can remove the runspaceid area this generates?

Comment: `$results | Select-Object Name, ExternalIP`

Comment: Remember to mark as answer if this solved your question so the question will be marked as closed.